# Does 83(b) cause a tax liability when exchanging startup stock for public stock?

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, start-up, 83b-election

I sold a startup to a public company. I filed an 83b at startup inception (nominal value).

The terms of the sale were such that I must vest the sale proceeds over 4 years  and will be realized as stock of the public company (this is independent of salary and equity package as part of employment). In one sense, I've traded startup stock for stock in the public company with a new 4 year vest.

I was highly encouraged to fill out an 83B at the time of sale where the "FMV" and the "amount paid" in they 83B were the *same* (semi-large) number.

I was told by the lawyers there was no tax consequence because the two numbers were the same. However, a tax professional tells me that since the start-up stock was "realized" there invokes a taxable event now.

Keep in mind, I've received none of that stock so far and won't for several more months. However, I'm now led to believe I owe cap-gains tax on the entire 4 year vest this year.  Who's right?

Answer (score 2):

> I was told by the lawyers there was no tax consequence because the two
>   numbers were the same.

That is correct.

> However, a tax professional tells me that since the start-up stock was
>   "realized" there invokes a taxable event now.

That is correct.

> I'm now led to believe I owe cap-gains tax on the entire 4 year vest
>   this year

That is incorrect.

You owe capital gains tax on the sale of your startup stock. Which is accidentally the exact same amount you "paid" for the new unvested stocks.

There's no taxable event with regards to the new stocks because the amount you paid for them was the amount you got for the old stocks.

But you did sell the old stocks, and that is a taxable event.

Comment: Isn't the "taxable event" a tax consequence, in that the OP owes tax earlier than it would otherwise have been owed? In the end the total tax paid will be the same as long if the new shares end up being worth more than they are now, but it might create a liquidity problem now as the OP doesn't have any cash from the share swap.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam no, the taxable event is the sale of the startup stocks. The new 83(b) is irrelevant, the sale of the startup stocks triggers capital gains regardless of what was done with the proceeds. You cannot defer taxes on stock sales. Liquidity may indeed be an issue. The OP should have had a tax consultation before making decisions.

Comment: Right, the end result makes sense, it just seems to me that the lawyers were wrong not to describe it as a "tax consequence".

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam the lawyers were right. It's just that they were talking about the 83(b) filing for the new stock. They didn't, and wouldn't, provide advice re the old stocks. None of their business.

Comment: If they were only talking about the new filing, why would the "because the two numbers were the same" be relevant?

Comment: The main point of disconnect is that there were two separate transactions: 1. Sale of the old stocks. 2. Filing 83(b) for the newly granted restricted stocks. The lawyers were only talking about (2) because that's what they were hired to talk about. The tax adviser talked about (1). These are **unrelated** transactions, from tax perspective.

Comment: "The two numbers were the same" is relevant because it explains why the 83(b) filing for the new restricted stocks had no tax consequences: there was no additional income imputed.

Comment: Hmm, ok. Still seems like misleading advice from the lawyers - the two transactions were certainly separate for tax purposes, but they sound like one *legal* transaction ("swap your old shares for new shares") - I can't imagine that the OP could have chosen to walk away with the cash from (1) and not execute (2). "We don't know about part of this" would of course have been fine, but "No tax consequence" has the wrong implication for me.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam that is a matter of expectations. I've learned to never expect a lawyer to answer anything beyond the most restricted scope of the engagement. The OP should have hired his own counsel and not rely on the counsel provided by the company, since they would not be engaged to provide him with tax advice re his personal tax matters. They were hired to deal with the planning for the new stocks, and that's what they did.